# Upload file to different domain on same Server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm confused about the path..!!!

I want to upload a files to a another domain hosted on same server.

**STRUCTURE:**
`-> abc.com
     - application
     - assets
        - upload
     - system
-> xyz.com 
     - application 
     - system`

Im running an upload function in `www.xyz.com` and I want to save the file inside the folder in `www.abc.com`.

I use the following line as path:
`$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/abc.com/assets/upload/'.$video_file_name;`

> The above path work fine in localhost server.

But it return a path like this:
`/home/www/xyz.com/abc.com/assets/upload/vid_15155833651401821.mp4`

I need the path as:
`/home/www/abc.com/assets/upload/vid_15155833651401821.mp4`

**CODE:**

```
function video()
{
      if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
      {
         $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['videourl']['name'][0], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

         $video_file_name = 'vid_'.time().rand(0,10000000).'.'.$extension;

         $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/abc.com/assets/upload/'.$video_file_name;
         // $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../abc.com/assets/upload/'.$video_file_name;
         // $path = 'home/www/abc.com/assets/upload/'.$video_file_name;
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["videourl"]["tmp_name"][0],$path);
         echo $video_file_name;
     }else{
        $this->load->view('test');
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` then, use the absolute path

Comment: How can i use absolute path? Can you please explain.

Comment: `$path = '/home/www/abc.com/assets/upload/'.$video_file_name;`

Comment: Failed.. It didn't work.

Comment: That's not a very descriptive error message. Did you check file permissions? Does the upload work if you upload to xyz.com?

Comment: Yes. I gave full permission. And the upload works fine on xyz.com. The error message is that : `Message: move_uploaded_file(/home/www/bawabba.com/assets/upload/vid_15155869184229798.mp4): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please show us the real path and the actual code you use to handle the upload. The error message you are pasting does not match what's in your question at all, making it very hard to debug and help you.

Comment: @Oldskool Updated with code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go "up" a directory, since the `xyz.com` shouldn't be there. So based on your current code, replace:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/abc.com/assets/upload/'.$video_file_name;
```

With

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../abc.com/assets/upload/'.$video_file_name;
```

Effectively adding the `../` after the document root variable. This should put the file in the right place.

Comment: It didn't work. Shows error `Message: move_uploaded_file(/home/www/xyz.com/../abc.com/assets/upload/vid_15155859969235963.mp4): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: Eh, where did the `assets/portf‌​olio_video` bit come from? You never mentioned that path. Try to include the full upload code in your question.

Comment: Sorry!!.. Edited. This is the full upload path.